# Why are my water supply lines deteriorating?

Tags: plumbing

I have an American Standard kitchen faucet from 2011. The hot and cold water supply line hoses are falling apart. The outside silver/grey layer has turned brown and flakes off. In the attached picture you can see the underneath whitengut of the hose, which looks ready to burst.

[image: Under sink image showing damaged flexible lines]

I'm trying to figure out what caused that, and I can only think that it was caused by vapors of chemicals stored in that same cabinet. Under the sink we have the usual stuff

- Dish detergent,
- CLR,
- Potatoes and onions in a bin,
- Windex

This can't be caused by the water itself; you can see the supply line to the removable faucet is perfectly fine in the picture (silver). Why didn't that one turn brown and peel off?

I have a replacement faucet coming and the supply line to the dishwasher is starting to brown out. Does anyone have any thoughts as to what may have caused hoses 3 years old to look like they are 30 years old?

Comment: Is this a beach house near salt water?

Comment: no sir, not in a beach house. THe odd thing is that it happened to the hot and cold suppy lines and not to the hose for the pullout faucet (you can see it intact in the picture).

Comment: Are there any electrical conductors connected to the plumbing in that area? It may be a reaction between the braided tubing and the fixed plumbing, from which the sprayer hose is isolated.  The heavy corrosion of the copper plumbing leads me to believe that the problem is with the fixed plumbing.

Comment: tester - good theory. There is an outlet at the bottom that has the dishwasher and garbage disposal attached; it has a plastic protective covering in case of splashes. Beside replacing the fixed plumbing (the green one), what can I do? Can I clean or coat that green pipe? It feeds the refrigerator's water line.

Comment: How old is the plumbing?

Comment: well, the house was built in 79, and we moved in 2 years ago. I assume that the previous owner had no reason to replace the copper water lines under the kitchen, but I don't know for certain. They do look like they are 30 years old. I imagine it wouldn't be too difficult or expensive to replace those 2 pipes coming out of the wall (hot and cold), but i'd like to avoid the expense. Can I coat them or paint them or something?

Comment: It might be more complicated than that.  If there is a [galvanic reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion) going on, you'll have to address the root cause. The copper plumbing in my house that was build in 1920, looks almost new. For there to be that much corrosion in only 30 some years, there is something strange going on.

Comment: wow. ok. I just thought about covering the 2 4-inch segments of pipe that stick out of the wall (hot and cold) with insulating foam that is used for air conditioning return lines. Covering them with that would completely isolate the pipes from whatever might be in the air. Do you think that might help? Although the supply line to the dishwasher is starting to turn brown on the outside and it doesnt touch anything. So, the corrosion must be affecting it from the inside.

Comment: Are the pipes exposed to high levels of humidity?

Comment: they were prior to my fixes over the weekend. The old dishwasher leaked for a while, and the wood of the cabinet began rotting. I assume that kept some humidity in the air, though I'm not sure. I read I can clean the pipes with vinegar and sodium bicarbonate, and I shall try that.

Comment: Is there a chance that the house was remodeled when the corrosive chinese drywall was used?  Sometime around 2004?

Comment: What's your location, climate?  Other unusual factors?  Where do those pipes come from?

Comment: You store onions under the sink... As the onions deteriorate, they release propanethiol S-oxide (same as cutting them) that combined with the moisture in the air, produce sulfur oxide which will corrode pipes.  Store the onions elsewhere.

Comment: Definitely looks airborne to be oxidizing the copper pipes on the outside. Is that a sewer pipe below?

Comment: Not posting as an answer because this is just speculation, but I'd think about storing the CLR elsewhere, because at least in its liquid form, it's bad for metal finishes.  Is it possible for it to generate fumes that degrade finishes?  I don't know, but I wouldn't take the chance.

Answer (score 3):

Might not be, but looks like, effects of sulfur out-gassing from drywall.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_drywall or Google 'Knauf Plasterboard Tianjin Co.'.  Drywall commonly emits sulfur gas, however some of the lots from China were apparently really bad.  The bad drywall was widely distributed, including at Home Depot.

Note: A lot of Home Depot Quality 'stainless steel' is not very stainless.  But your picture shows a situation well beyond that.  Everything under that sink looks 50 years old: note the corrosion on the pipes and valves as well.